# What WSDL URL to use for SOAP using Sandbox account?

Tags: docusignapi

I have a sandbox account with DocuSign and I plan to use SoapUI to test sending an envelope to DocuSign via web services.  What wsdl URL should I use for the sandbox account please?

Also, if I want to switch to use REST instead of SOAP, what URL should I use for REST please?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

## Primary domains for DocuSign Web Service

### Live (Production)

https://www.docusign.net or [https://na2.docusign.net]](https://demo.docusign.net) - this is only for Live (in-production) use.  Usage is dictated by purchased plan contract.  Certification is required before API integrated applications can make calls into this environment.

**Note:** Prod sites are NA1 (www.docusign.net), NA2 (na2.docusign.net), and EU1 (eu1.docusign.net)

**Note:** EU1 is normally reserved for accounts operating predominately outside of the Western hemisphere.

### Sandbox (Demo)

https://demo.docusign.net  - this is for development and testing.  This site is similar to Production environment but not quite as scalable/stable.  Usage is free.  This site also serves as the Disaster Recovery site and should always be included in any IP Address/URL tables used for configuration/allowed access.

### SOAP

**DocuSign SOAP endpoints & WSDL:**

In general,

```
https://{site}.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx?wsdl
```

Browsing to https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx provides a page listing the methods, with links to display samples of the SOAP body structure for invoking the method (sample includes request and response).

**Examples for NA1:**

```
https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx?wsdl
https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/Credential.asmx?wsdl
https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/accountmanagement.asmx?wsdl
```

### REST

```
https://www.docusign.net/restapi/help
```

## API Endpoints

**X-DocuSign-Authentication HTTP header used like REST** see this post [How should the header X-DocuSign-Authentication be used for REST and SOAP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028119/how-should-the-header-x-docusign-authentication-be-used-for-rest-and-soap/22028120#22028120)

### SOAP

```
https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx 
https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/Credential.asmx
https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/accountmanagement.asmx
```

### SCHEMA

```
https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/schema/dsx.xsd
```

**Authentication via WS-Security UsernameToken in SOAP Header.**

**Note:** this endpoint has 4 additional obsolete methods not available via dsapi.asmx endpoint. Recommend you avoid this endpoint unless you need WS-Security or the 4 obsolete methods: (oldest but shown in many samples)

```
https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx
```

### REST

**X-DocuSign-Authentication Header needed** see this post [How should the header X-DocuSign-Authentication be used for REST and SOAP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028119/how-should-the-header-x-docusign-authentication-be-used-for-rest-and-soap/22028120#22028120)

```
https://www.docusign.net/restapi/
https://www.docusign.net/restapi/v1
https://www.docusign.net/restapi/v2
```

Answer (score 3):

The information you're requesting is in the documentation for each API.

[SOAP API Guide](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm)

[REST API Guide](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/)

I recommend reading through each guide, they're filled with a lot of the basic questions and answers to get you up and running.

Answer (score 3):

The DocuSign SOAP API guide specifies the WSDL URLs for the DocuSign *Production* environment.  Simply replace "**www**" with "**demo**" in those URLs and you'll have the WSDL URLs for the DocuSign *Demo* environment.  i.e., in the DocuSign *Demo* environment, the WSDL for the DocuSign Service API is:  `https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/schema/dsapi.wsdl`

Comment: I'm totally new to DocuSign.  I created a template and I have a pdf file sitting on my local machine in the directory C:\Temp\test.pdf.  I want to send this pdf document and use the template.  I'm looking at the CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates API and it's so overwhelming with so many fields.  Do you have a sample SOAP XML request for this API that will help me get started?

Comment: Please post as new question; thanks.  Also, if you haven't already done so, check out the DocuSign Developer Center (http://www.docusign.com/developer-center) -- that contains a wealth of information about using the DocuSign APIs, including some good 'getting started'-type material.