# How should the header X-DocuSign-Authentication be used for REST and SOAP?

Tags: rest, soap, docusignapi

What are the options in and formats for using the header "X-DocuSign-Authentication" when used for REST and SOAP?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### [X-DocuSign-Authentication](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/legacy_auth.html) [HTTP HEADER]

- **Best Practice:** Use an obfuscated username and password in the api authentication header
- **Definition:**  Send On Behalf Of Rights (API)  is SOBO.

**Given the following values:**

- Username == API Service User ==
  “service.account.user.member@domain.com” == USERID
  “cdcd3fc7-2b3c-40d4-98ed-ff90add317ca”
- Password == “yourpassword” = EncryptedAPIPassword ==
  “/A5hpPhSczID+JNEKZbg5mYf7+7=”
- SOBOUser == “user.member@domain.com” == USERID
  “eacd3fc7-2b3c-40d4-98ed-ff90add317ff“
- Integratorkey == “YDMN-339fa93c-fcf0-4390-8141-2e0f071ffa2e”

Your code needs to result in a http header value for the HTTP header
   X-DocuSign-Authentication of:

### **XML format:**

**NON-SOBO**

```
<DocuSignCredentials><Username>cdcd3fc7-2b3c-40d4-98ed-ff90add317ca</Username><Password>/A5hpPhSczID+JNEKZbg5mYf7+7=</Password><IntegratorKey>YDMN-339fa93c-fcf0-4390-8141-2e0f071ffa2e </IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
```

**SOBO**

```
<DocuSignCredentials><Username>cdcd3fc7-2b3c-40d4-98ed-ff90add317ca</Username><Password>/A5hpPhSczID+JNEKZbg5mYf7+7=</Password><IntegratorKey>YDMN-339fa93c-fcf0-4390-8141-2e0f071ffa2e</IntegratorKey><SendOnBehalfOf>eacd3fc7-2b3c-40d4-98ed-ff90add317ff </SendOnBehalfOf></DocuSignCredentials>
```

### **JSON format:**

**NON-SOBO**

```
{"Username":"cdcd3fc7-2b3c-40d4-98ed-ff90add317ca","Password":"/A5hpPhSczID+JNEKZbg5mYf7+7=","IntegratorKey":"YDMN-339fa93c-fcf0-4390-8141-2e0f071ffa2e"}
```

SOBO

```
{"Username":"cdcd3fc7-2b3c-40d4-98ed-ff90add317ca","Password":"/A5hpPhSczID+JNEKZbg5mYf7+7=","SendOnBehalfOf":"eacd3fc7-2b3c-40d4-98ed-ff90add317ff","IntegratorKey":"YDMN-339fa93c-fcf0-4390-8141-2e0f071ffa2e"}
```

**API Service user**
Service Account doesn’t need to be Admin, unless you are creating users, but must have SOBO and Account Wide rights.

**SOBO User**
SOBO User doesn’t need to be Admin, but must have the permission to send and be a user in the account of the Service Account user. You only use this userid when you are doing an action as that user like sending or voiding.

[Here is a link to the full sized Infographic I created to assist with this shown below](https://blog.grigsbyconsultingllc.com/x-docusign-authentication-best-practices-for-docusign-via-rest-or-soap-infographic/)

[image: X-DocuSign-Authentication Inforgraphic]

Comment: Great detailed answer Grigs!

Comment: How do I generate "obfuscated  username" and "encrypted password"?

Comment: what's the encryption I should be using?

Comment: make the api call /restapi/v2/login_information?api_password=true (notice the parameter for api_password=true.

and look for the node at the bottom of the response 

"apiPassword": "encrpytedpassword"