# Docusign with Thunderhead - Webservice Error

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I am trying to use `Docusign` with Thunderhead in `Salesforce`.

I created a Thunderhead Template, Generate Report Button, and in the Application Settings of the Thunderhead I added the `Docusign` Settings.

However, it comes up with an error,

Error:

```
Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: The request element was not recognized. faultcode=soap:Client faultactor=
```

Could you please help me resolve this issue.

Thank You

Regards,

Lavanya

Comment: Assuming you are using this Thunderhead http://www.thunderhead.com/how-we-do-it/one-collaborate-for-salesforce/

I suspect since you are using a broker for your web service you goal is not to get into the nitty gritty of development.

Problem is providing only an error message does little in allowing us developers to assist you. Please update your question with what API you tried to call and how it was setup in the Thunderhead template.

If you can provide screen shots with your credentials redacted it would also be helpful

Comment: Thanks David, It was actually the Username field that was the problem. In the Docusign Help they mentioned to enter [Integration Key] Username as a combination to the username field, but in actual scenario just the username worked without any key in the front.

Comment: Excellent - This link should help clear up how to use the X-DocuSign-Authentication    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028119/how-should-the-header-x-docusign-authentication-be-used-for-rest-and-soap/22028120#22028120