# User in docusign

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, docusignapi

I have to integrate Docusign with my ASP.Net web application.In our application there are many companies and each company has Administrators and Users.I want to clarify something related to Integrator key required in below mentioned scenarios.

1)If only administrators are allowed to send documents for signing to other users.
In this case,do all the Administrators need to have separate Integrator key for sending documents for signing?

2)If all users are allowed to send documents for signing to other users.
In this case do all users of my application are required to have separate integrator key?

In short I really want to know how users can be managed with Integrator key?
Would it be 1 such account per Company, or 1 per initiator within a company?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually none of the above.  A DocuSign **Integrator Key** is similar to what other APIs call their **API key** (Google for instance).  It is used to identify a given DocuSign Integration, so you actually only need **1** Integrator Key for your entire integration.  You can think of it as a "per app" or "per integration" key, not per user.

See [this page](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/quick-start/first-api-call) in the DocuSign Dev Center for more information.

Comment: Also you may want to reference this StackOverflow question and answer to see how you will want to setup your authentication and best practices using your DocuSign integrator key http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028119/how-should-the-header-x-docusign-authentication-be-used-for-rest-and-soap/22028120#22028120

Comment: Ok.Understood,thanks.How will the users who want to send the documents for signing will be managed?By this 1 integrator key(generated by developer account) will all the users of my application be able to send documents for signing? or do they also need to have account on Docusign?

Comment: You need a DocuSign account just for the users who will be creating and sending signature requests.. the recipients (signers) never need to their own account (signing is always free).  For any user that will be creating/sending requests the Integrator Key will go into the authorization header in each API call.  See here for more info:  https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/quick-start/first-api-call