# DocusignAPI Authentication with PHP: "Integrator key was not specified"

Tags: php, docusignapi

I'm working on my first DocuSign API implementation and I'm having trouble authenticating to the REST API.

Following the API docs, I can authenticate successfully through using curl on the command line:

```
$ curl --request GET 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information' --header 'Content-Type:application/json' --header 'Accept:application/json' --header 'X-DocuSign-Authentication:{"<redacted>", "Password": "<redacted>", "IntegratorKey": "<redacted>"}'
{
  "loginAccounts": [
    {
      "name": "<redacted>",
      "accountId": "<redacted>",
      "baseUrl": "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/<redacted>",
      "isDefault": "true",
      "userName": "<redacted>",
      "userId": "<redacted>",
      "email": "<redacted>",
      "siteDescription": ""
    }
  ]
```

However, when trying to authenticate using an HTTP request through PHP, I receive a '401 Unauthorized' response, with the body:

```
'{
  "errorCode": "PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",
  "message": "The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified."
}'
```

I'm pretty sure I'm setting an IntegratorKey header. My PHP code looks like:

```
$request = new \http\Client\Request('GET', $url, $this->getHeaders());
$client = new \http\Client();
$client->enqueue($request)->send();
$response = $client->getResponse();
```

I'm using the pecl/http-v2 HTTP library (docs at: http://devel-m6w6.rhcloud.com/mdref/http )

$url evals to:  `'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information'`

The header array looks like:

```
array (size=3)
    0 => string 'X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username": "<redacted>", "Password":  "<redacted>", "IntegratorKey": "<redacted>"}' (length=155)
    1 => string 'Content-Type: application/json' (length=30)
    2 => string 'Accept: application/json' (length=24)
```

It appears the API key isn't being received, even though I can see the proper headers are being sent. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks for your help!

*Edit:* Fixed a missing double-quote around the password field in the authentication header. I had accidentally removed it while redacting the password. The authentication header matches character-for-character with the header used in the (working) 'curl' command.

Comment: Jeremy, I recommend you change the endpoint to "webhookapp" endpoint or other capture tool to capture what is being sent aka http://old.webhookapp.com/4748419621754361402 to see what iw realling being sent from your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point, it looks like the HTTP library I used is the source of the problem. I switched to [GuzzleHttp](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and the API calls worked without issue.

I suspect the array where I specified the headers was not given in the correct format. It could have been a key => value format instead, but I haven't had the time/interest in testing this. Guzzle seems to be more modern and is working, so I haven't bothered going back to the pecl package.

Answer (score 0):

Please Review [How should the header X-DocuSign-Authentication be used for REST and SOAP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028119/how-should-the-header-x-docusign-authentication-be-used-for-rest-and-soap)  as I think your " (quotes " ") are missing for the json "key" : "value"...

and it suspect this sample may serve you from http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/requestSignatureFromTemplate :

```
$data = array("accountId" => $accountId, 
    "emailSubject" => "DocuSign API - Signature Request from Template",
    "templateId" => $templateId, 
    "templateRoles" => array( 
            array( "email" => $email, "name" => $recipientName, "roleName" => $templateRoleName )),
    "status" => "sent");                                                                    

$data_string = json_encode($data);  
$curl = curl_init($baseUrl . "/envelopes" );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
    "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )                                                                       
);
```

Comment: Thanks @david-w-grigsby, good catch! Unfortunately, it's not the source of the problem. The missing double quote around the password field was just me getting carried away with the redaction. I'll edit the question to correct this.

In my PHP code, I've copy-pasted the X-DocuSign-Authentication header from my working 'curl' command, which _should_ eliminate that as a possible source.