# docuSign /v2/login_information Authenticate User to get BaseURL

Tags: docusignapi

I'm passing **Authorization** information in **json** format as following.

> X-DocuSign-Authentication:{ "Username" :"xxxxx", "Password" :"xxxxxx",
>   "IntegratorKey" :"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" }

I'm converting it `ToBase64String` and pass it to **docuSign restapi**.

It gives me UnAuthorised user error with status code 401.

I want to know which format and encoding i have to pass to "/v2/login_information" to get baseURL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No encoding is required for the [X-DocuSign-Authentication](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/legacy_auth.html) header.

Also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22028120/1219543) for more detailed explanation.

Comment: Header and error I'm getting

GET https://demo.docusign.net/restApi/v2/login_information?login_settings=all HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-AU,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: Bearer 'X-DocuSign-Authentication:{ "Username" :"xxxxx@xxx.com", "Password" :"RGlzaGFudDE5ODQ=", "IntegratorKey" :"IntegratorKey" }'
User-Agent: RestSharp/104.4.0.0
Host: demo.docusign.net
Connection: Keep-Alive

  "errorCode": "AUTHORIZATION_INVALID_TOKEN",

can you please let me what I'm missing

Comment: You are passing an invalid format. If you are using the legacy authentication you have to pass the X-DocuSign-Authentication as header name. You are passing Authorization header which is applicable for [oAuth](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_auth_code.html).