# Exception: [401] Error connecting to the API (https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information)

Tags: php

I am trying to create code for sending document for signature request using docusign API:

1. I already downloaded the PHP SDK
2. I already opened a developer sandbox account
3. But after filling in some info in the PHP SDK file and run, it gave me the above error.

I am guessing the error may mean that I have not  gone through the steps to configure client and request authorization code.
I tried to follow the steps on that page, but the instructions are so vague and difficult to follow. I clicked on the 'use sandbox account data' on the upper right corner of the C# code, but it only asked me to log in to my account and directed me back to the same page.

I don't know where to start from there. 
I need a more step-by-step instruction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

@T. Nguyen  401 translates to an unauthorized API request and the response should say which part is wrong aka the username / password or Integrator Key is incorrect.

I really suggest using PostMan Client and / or SoapUI to validate you can get login information and see the actual error returned, as it will say Integrator Key or Username/Password in the response. PostMan or SoapUI will issue the actual API calls successfully (Demo or Prod once you have passed prod API certification) showing you the actual response without having to worry about coding typo's, properties of objects or debugging logging to see what really came back.

This allows you to learn the DocuSign API while using the PHP SDK. You did the right thing asking for help here on Stack Overflow.

I have a couple links for you to get started:

1. DocuSign Developer Center where you probably found the PHP SDK https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/sdk-tools
2. Link for info on PostMan (older version, you can get the latest one - aka Orange Rocket Man logo vs blue world, for Chrome or Mac Standalone - https://blog.grigsbyconsultingllc.com/postman-rest-client-a-google-chrome-app/
3. X-DocuSign-Authentication Header Q&A on StackOverflow [How should the header X-DocuSign-Authentication be used for REST and SOAP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028119/how-should-the-header-x-docusign-authentication-be-used-for-rest-and-soap)
4. I like the concept of the DocuSign API explorer to start with, sad part is it doesn't work against prod, so you still have to use something else when you move from demo to prod.

Best of Luck and Enjoy your DocuSign API journey!

Answer (score 1):

You can set  $config->setDebug(true) in dev environment and have all the errors displayed.

Answer (score 0):

to fetch error use this

```
try{
    //send request
}
catch (DocuSign\eSign\ApiException $ex){
    print_R($ex); //<--- print normal readeble error
    echo "Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```